# throw new Exception vs Catch block

Tags: c#

Is there any behavioural difference between:

```
if (s == null) // s is a string
{
 throw new NullReferenceException();
}
```

And:

```
try
{
  Console.Writeline(s);
}


catch (NullReferenceException Ex)
{ // logic in here 
}
```

Both throw exceptions of null object, if s is null. The first example is more readable as it shows exactly where the error occurs (the exception bit is right next to the line which will cause the exception).

I have seen this coding style a lot on various blogs by various coders of all sorts of skill levels, but why not just perform the main logic by checking if s is not null and thus save the exception from ever being raised? Is there a downside to this approach?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, `Console.WriteLine(null)` won't throw an exception. It will just print nothing out. Now assuming you meant something like:

```
Console.WriteLine(s.Length);
```

then it makes sense... and you should use the first form. Exceptions should occur when you can't predict them ahead of time with your current information. If you can easily work out that something's wrong, it makes no sense to try an operation which is bound to fail. It leads to code which is harder to understand and performs worse.

So `NullReferenceException`, `ArgumentNullException` and the like shouldn't be caught unless they're due to a [nasty API which sometimes throws exceptions which you can handle, but which shouldn't really be being thrown in the first place](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx). This is why in Code Contracts, the default behaviour for a failed contract is to throw an exception which you *can't* catch explicitly, other than by catching *everything* (which is typically somewhere at the top of the stack).

Comment: Thanks. I meant any case where the variable is used (in a method/ctor) but causes a NullReferenceException or object reference not set to an instance of an object error. One thing I was told by a friend who codes is that the first form should be used where the exception will be caught by the caller? So if I have another method which calls the first form and has a catch block for the thrown exception line. Would you agree with this?

Comment: What, if any, is the relationship between object reference not set to an instance of an object and NRE?

Comment: How do you know if the exception will be caught by the caller ?
And what is the difference between explicitly throwing an exception when something will go wrong (which is far more informative) and letting the .NET framework throw a generic NullRef exception ?

Comment: This one? http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx

Comment: Quoting Framework Design Guidelines, "DO NOT allow publicly callable APIs to explicitly or implicitly throw NullReferenceException..." 
See also http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2004/07/11/180315.aspx

Comment: (I had searched for "vexatious exceptions" instead of "vexing exceptions." Close but no cigar.)

Answer (score 2):

As Jon Skeet already mentioned, `Console.WriteLine (null)` won't throw an exception.

Next to that, I'd like to say that you should 'fail fast'.   That means that you have to put 'guard' clauses in your methods, and check the arguments that have been given in your methods if they can be considered to be valid.
This allows you to throw an exception yourself, and give an additional message which will be helpfull when debugging.   The message can give a clear indication on what was wrong, and that is much handier then if you're faced with a NullReferenceException that has been thrown without any good information in it's message property.

Answer (score 1):

If you are writing a class library there may be occasions when you know that if a certain parameter contains a null value, that may cause trouble further down the line. In those cases I usually find it to be a good idea to throw an exception (even though I would probably use `ArgumentNullException` for that case) to make the user of the class library aware of this as early and clearly as possible.

Exceptions are not always a bad thing.

Answer (score 1):

Jon Skeet is right but, more generally, it's all a question of semantic.

If the situation has some applicative meaning  (number out of bound, date of birth in the future, etc) you may want to test for it before doing any operation and throw a custom exception (that is one with meaning for your application).

If the situation is truly "exceptional", just write the code as if the given value were correct. See, if you put the test, you will do it everytime, knowing that the VM will do it anyway in case it needs to throw an exception. From a performance point of view, if the error happens to have a statistically small occurence, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you're taking a Design By Contract type approach to things then a piece of code can specify that it throws exceptions in order to specify its contract and to enforce it. The other half is, of course, calling code recognising the contract and fulfilling it.

In this case it would mean that if you know a method will throw an exception if you pass in null (i.e. its contract is that you don't pass nulls) then you should check before calling it.

Jon Skeet says that the method won't throw an exception anyway. That may or may not be true but the principle of guarding for method contract stands (which I believe was the point of your question).